# Updating map multiple times in F#

Tags: dictionary, f#

Let's say I have a map `M:Map<int, bool>` (initially empty). I want to update this time. I have a list `L = [1 .. 100]` and for each element in this list, I want to set the corresponding value in `M` false. So something like, `[1 .. 100] |> List.map (fun x -> M.Add(x, false))`. But `M.Add()` returns a new map every time and the updates are not reflected. How can I do this update in an idiomatic F# way?

Comment: It's easier if you show us the source you've got so far, so that we can explain exactly the part you don't understand, and what options you have. We can also guess, but might miss some of your problems in understanding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a fold for this:

```
let m = [1 .. 100] 
        |> List.fold( fun (acc:Map<int,bool>) x -> acc.Add(x, false)) Map.empty
```

A fold takes an accumulator and the current value as parameters.  You can here use the Add method to return the updated Map.

For your specific scenario you may also consider a dictionary:

```
let m2 = [1 .. 100] 
         |>List.map(fun x->(x,false))
         |>dict
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I got a working solution. Instead of declaring a Map first and then updating it (which would return a new Map every time), I constructed a list first and then converted the list to a Map.

```
[1 .. 100]
|> List.map
   (fun x ->
       (x, false)
   )
|> Map.ofList
```

I don't know if this solution is any good as I'm fairly new to F#. I'll be glad to know if this solution can be improved.

Comment: That is fine. I gave you a few other options below.